# How do I access the component that is modified by the directive in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular2-directives

Let us assume a hypothetical situation. You and I have a component (named **AComponent**) identified by the selector `a-component`, and a directive identified by the selector `[is-modified]`.

In another component's definition file, we use the following template that combines our component and our directive, which modifies the component:

```
<a-component is-modified></a-component>
```

The [documentation for a attribute **Directive**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) indicates that the constructor gives the directive access to the **ElementRef**, but there is no link from **ElementRef** to the **Component** parent.

```
export class IsModifiedDirective
{
    constructor( elementReference : ElementRef )
    {
        console.log( elementReference );

        //no connection appears to exist between elementReference and the component
        //also: ElementRef has security risks, so it should be avoided.

        debugger;
    }
}
```

I tried using injection to inject the necessary component and changed the `ElementRef` to a `ComponentRef<AComponent>`; this gave the error that no provider is specified for **ComponentRef**.  I then tried to inject the component `AComponent`, but that generated errors as well.

The documentation clearly indicates that "Attribute directives—change the appearance or behavior of an element, **component**, or another directive.", but I do not see how the Directive obtains access to the **component** that it modifies.

Can anyone provide assistance?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found here:  [Component Interactions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

The secret to communication is to inject a service into the constructors.  I extended the Component and the Directive to use the same service:

```
//The Component Definition (Psuedocode)
@Component(
{
   ...,
   providers: [ AService ],
   ...
}
)
export class AComponent
{
    constructor( commonService : AService )
    {
         let comp : AComponent = this;
         commonService.serviceAnnouncement$.subscribe(
             (msg)=>{
                  //msg can be anything we like, in my specific instance,
                  //I passed a reference to the directive instance

                  comp.doSomethingWithMsg( msg );
             }
         );
    }

}
```

--

```
//The Directive Definition (Psuedocode)
@Directive(...)
export class IsModifiedDirective
{
    constructor( commonService : AService )
    {
         commonService.announceSomething( this );
    }
}
```

--

```
//The Service Definition (Psuedocode)
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable(...)
export class AService
{
    private source = new Subject<MsgType>();

    serviceAnnouncement$ = this.source.toObservable();

    announceSomething( msg : MsgType )
    {
         this.source.next( msg );
    }
}
```

The above classes exist in their own files. The imports and other code are mostly left out to avoid cluttering the display.  They key is that the objects can pass instances of themselves to other objects listening to the shared service.  The documentation suggests that the `providers` attribute of the @Component decorator might establish a unique provider shared by that component and its descendants; I have not tested this implied feature.

If you are reading this, it is important to note that the communication used above, where the directive passes itself to the component, only works for my specific case, and the message that is passed between your objects should be specific to your implementation.